# Manage settings in an application

Tags: laravel

Mine is a self-taught question, I would like to better understand how to best deal with the settings of an application in Laravel.

Assuming you have a table "Settings":

| option | value |
| --- | --- |
| site_name | Example_name |
| site_description | Example_description |

How can I handle the update issue? And how can I take them?

Comment: What is the update issue you're experiencing? What do you mean by "take them"?

Comment: I would like to know having seen the specific database schema, how to get an entry, for example (site_name), and how can I create a clean code in the controller associated with a form that manages all these fields?

Comment: Check out this [Simple Laravel CRUD with Resource Controllers](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers) from Digital Ocean. I think it will help get you going.

Comment: Also check out this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/163606/configuration-data-single-row-table-vs-name-value-pair-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use out-of-the-box Laravel you can create a model to assist you with that. In order for you to create a model, you can run `php artisan make:model Setting` or you can create a model manually. Below is an example which you should place in a new file (`Setting.php`) in the /App/Models directory.

```
<?php
            
namespace App\Models;
            
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
            
class Setting extends Model
{

   /**
   * The table associated with the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
   protected $table = 'Settings';

   /**
   * The primary key associated with the table.
   *
   * @var string
   */
   protected $primaryKey = 'option';

   /**
   * Indicates if the model's ID is auto-incrementing.
   *
   * @var bool
   */
   public $incrementing = false;

   /**
   * The data type of the auto-incrementing ID.
   *
   * @var string
   */
   protected $keyType = 'string';

   /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
   protected $fillable = ['option', 'value'];

}
```

You can then create a controller by running the following command: `php artisan make:controller SettingController --resource --model=Setting`. The command will automatically create a resource controller for the Setting model based on the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller).

In your controller, you can request a certain value of one of your settings by using the following code:

```
// Retrieve a model by its primary key...
$site_name = Setting::find('site_name')->value;
```

Or you can request all settings listed in your database by using this line:

```
// Retrieve all settings
$settings = Setting::all();
```

You can further process the settings with code like this:

```
// Create a list of all options and associated values
foreach ($settings as $setting) {
   echo $setting->option . ": " . $setting->value;
}
```

You can find way more information about Laravel models in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent) and online.
I haven't tested the codes but they should work.

#### Update all options

If you want to update all options you should create a HTML form like this one:

```
<form action="{{ route('setting.update') }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   @method('PUT')
   @foreach ($settings as $setting)
      <label>{{ $setting->option }}</label>
      <input type="text" name="{{ $setting->option }}" value="{{ $setting->value }}"/>
   @endforeach
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In your update() function in your controller you can then update all values by using the following code:

```php
public function update(Request $request)
{
   $settings = Setting::update($request->all());
}
```

I'm not sure if the update will work correctly with the code above so please let me know :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I put a vote on you. I was wondering seeing the new database schema, how to update the data in a form with all the various settings, before I did this:$update = Settings::first()->update([
            'site_name' => request('site_name'),
            'site_tagline' => request('site_tagline'),
            'site_description' => request('site_description')
        ]);

Comment: Hi @Bonny, I've updated my answer. Is this what you mean? If so, could you please check if it works? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I have to manage various types of inputs, putting them within a cycle I am forced to use only one type. To explain me better, think as if you are updating some app settings, where some fields are and are not changed.

Answer (score 1):

Spatie offer an open-source solution to managing laravel settings: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-settings I use a number of their other open-source solutions and they make life very easy.

Great material to learn from even if you decide not to use their package.